# CSV File showing HTML page source

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, csv

I am exporting a CSV file from an ASP .NET page but somehow it contains HTML code and the data that are supposed to be exported (ie. 29 rows) are not complete (ie from supposedly 29 rows, only 17 shows up, and then HTML all the way down).

[image: CSV File Preview]

Here are my codes:

```
    private void WriteToCSV()
    {
        var clientId = int.Parse(ddlClients.SelectedValue);
        var taskTypeId = int.Parse(ddlTaskType.SelectedValue);

        var mtComponent = new MainTableComponent();
        var data = mtComponent.GetMainTableRecords(clientId, 0, taskTypeId);

        if (data == null || data.Count == 0)
        {
            ShowAlertMessage("No available data to export.");
            return;
        }

        var callerId = GetClientList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClientId == clientId).CallerId;

        string attachment = string.Concat("attachment; filename=CallList_", ddlClients.SelectedItem.Text,
            "_", ddlTaskType.SelectedItem.Text, "_", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), ".csv");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("row,phone1,phone2,phone3,caller_id");

        foreach (var d in data)
            WriteUserInfo(d, callerId);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }

    private void WriteUserInfo(MainTableEntity person, string callerId)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        AddComma(person.RowNumber.ToString(), stringBuilder);
        AddComma(FormatNumber(person.MobileNumber), stringBuilder);
        AddComma("", stringBuilder);
        AddComma("", stringBuilder);
        AddComma(callerId, stringBuilder);
        stringBuilder.Remove(stringBuilder.Length - 1, 1);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(stringBuilder.ToString());
    }

    private void AddComma(string value, StringBuilder stringBuilder)
    {
        value.Replace(",", "");
        stringBuilder.Append(value).Append(",");
    }

    private string FormatNumber(string number)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(number))
            return null;

        string n = number.Replace('-', ' ').Replace(" ", "").Trim();

        return n;
    }
```

The funny thing is, this does not happen on my local machine and on our test environment. It only happens in our production environment.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you get the option of downloading or saving the file?

Comment: And try to take out the `HttpContext.Current.Response.End()` this can be your problem...

Comment: The file is downloaded and saved automatically.

Comment: If I remove the Response.End(), will it not cause any issue?

Comment: Have a look here http://bresleveloper.blogspot.nl/2014/07/aspnet-ending-response-options.html